openpyxl merges only first file
I want to collate two excel files with openpyxl

However it adds only one file and not second file.

import os;import pdb
from openpyxl import load_workbook

destfile=mypath+'dest_s1s2.xlsx'
ws2=load_workbook(destfile)
wsd=ws2.active

list1=[mypath+'source1.xlsx',mypath+'source2.xlsx']

for bk in range(0,2):
 wsourc=load_workbook(list1[bk])
 wss1=wsourc.active
 mr=len(wss1['a'])
 mc = wss1.max_column
 mrd = wsd.max_row
 mcd = wsd.max_column
 if bk==0:
  s=1
 else:
  s=2
 for i in range (s, mr + 1):
  for j in range (1, mc + 1):   
 # reading cell value from source excel file  # copying the cell values from source # excel file to destination excel file 
   c = wss1.cell(row = i, column = j) 
 # writing the read value to destination excel file
   #h=-1 if s==2 else h=0
   if s==2:
    h=-1
   else:
    h=0
   #wsd.cell(row = mrd+i+h, column = j).value = c.value
    wsd.cell(row = mrd+i, column = j).value = c.value
    print(os.path.basename(list1[bk]))
    pdb.set_trace()
    #print('pdb.set_trace=lambda:None')
 wsourc.close()

 # saving the destination excel file 
ws2.save(destfile)
ws2.close()

I tried to merge two files.
the script will exclude pasting first row starting from second file
but it entirely omits second file

On the 2nd source workbook at if bk==0: the value of 's' is set to 2; s=2. Then later your code has;  if s == 2: h = -1 and nothing else is done with that cell. Don't know what 'h' is for it's not used anywhere else in the code.

when i  uncommnet the line wsd.cell(row = mrd+i+h, column = j).value = c.value it works perfectly (at the same time i will commnet below line)

It solved by using enumerate and script "if file_index > 0 and row_index == 0: continue" Thanks moken
